# active class to menu item

Tags: jquery, url, addclass

I have a main menu and a side menu in each internal page; when I select an item in the main menu adds the class "active" element to it, but when I select an item in the lateral menu does not add the class "active".
I need to add the class "active" to "li" from the main menu whenever entering a page or their daughters.

Comment: Separately, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [*How do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: Thanks, really I am new to this site and do not speak English